# Retrieve json data with jquery ajax cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, cross-domain

I try to retrieve json data from other domain with jquery ajax, but it doesn't work. This is my code:

```
function getLeague() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://otherdomainurl.ashx?username=xxx&pass=xxx&type=xxx',
        headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data) {
            alert('Success');
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert('Fail');
        }
    });
}
```

i've tried to remove header, async, and crossDomain. i've tried to change the dataType to json. But it always give a fail alert. I use django(but i think it's not the problem). Thanks..

Comment: my guess is that the data type does not match

Comment: @guradio when i access the url with the browser, it shows json data...

Comment: then this one is wrong `dataType: 'jsonp',`

Comment: @guradio i've change the dataType to json. it still not working.

Comment: see ... there must be some errors in console.

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla the error in the console is "uncaught SyntaxError: unexpexted token :"

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla when i change the datatype into json. The error is Response to preflight request doesnt pass access control check: No 'Access -Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 1):

This header needs to be on the server side, not client side.

Try [Django CORS Headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers):

> A Django App that adds CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) headers to responses.
>
> Although JSON-P is useful, it is strictly limited to GET requests. CORS builds on top of XmlHttpRequest to allow developers to make cross-domain requests, similar to same-domain requests.

Comment: i tried this, and its not working too. Then, i look into django-http-proxy and it solve the problem

Comment: @Krisnadi how exactly did this help you?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623792/django-cors-headers-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is at **async: false**.

> Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support
> synchronous operation

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

So. do your really need to set async: false?

Comment: yes, i've tried to remove the async too. But it still not working.

Comment: So, change your error function to
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
       
         alert(xhr.responseText);
      }
To see what happend

Comment: error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.status); alert(xhr.responseText);alert(thrownError); }

Comment: it shows 200, undefined, Error: jQuery111202094834523741156_1456300030623 was not called

Comment: In this case, error may be from the dataType. Are you sure the returning data is a valida json. change dataType to text or html to see is there anything change. or copy return json from your browser and validate at http://jsonlint.com/. let try.

Comment: i validate the return on jsonlint.com, it's valid. i tried to change the dataType into script. it's success. But i dont understand how to handle "script" datatype. is it same with json?

Answer (score -1):

Try Below code

```
function getLeague() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://otherdomainurl.ashx',
    data: {Your Obj},
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Success');
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert('Fail');
    }
});
```

}

Comment: make sure, from server side you getting JSON data only

Comment: i tried this : error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.status); alert(xhr.responseText);alert(thrownError); }

Comment: and it shows 200, undefined, Error: jQuery111202094834523741156_1456300030623 was not called

Comment: i validate on jsonlint.com and it's valid json