# Django-cors-headers not working

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, django-cors-headers

My django version is 1.8.6. I've copy the corsheaders folder into the project folder. i've pip install django-cors-headers(ver 1.1.0). This is my setting.py:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'MyWebsite_app',
    'storages',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

This is my jquery:

```
function getLeague() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://otherdomain.ashx?username=xxx&password=xxx&sportsBook=xxx&sportsType=xxx&gameType=xxx',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Success');
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('Fail');
    }
    });
}
```

It keeps alerting "Fail" when executing the getLeague(). And when i see the console it shows "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://otherdomain.ashx?username=xxx&password=xxx&sportsBook=xxx&sportsType=xxx&gameType=xxx. No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested source". Should i add some code in the urls.py or in the view.py? Thank you.

Comment: `dataType: 'jsonp',` instead or can you post what is the output of the url?

Comment: @Jai i've tried jsonp too. but it doesnt work too. this is the return sample: {"Msg":"","t":1456383442,"IsFullRefresh":true,"Refresh":[{"UID":"3e9b72f916de06f619ebeb8493f34817","CID":"1dcdbcab"}]} i've check in jsonlin.com and it is a valid json.

Comment: I don't work on django apps but you have a trailing comma here ` 'corsheaders',`.

Comment: @Jai thank you for your reply. but in django trailing comma wont be a problem. i think thats not the problem

Comment: try with comment out `'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',` from `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`

Comment: @itzmeontv i've tried that too before. but its not working too.

Comment: `http://otherdomain.ashx` if this is accessible then you have to enable cors here not on your application in django, but one thing you can do is to create a proxy at your application which in turn will communicate with the otherdomain and returns you the result.

Comment: @Jai can you tell me how to create a proxy? When i run the url in postman or in the web browser, it returned the json data. But when i request via ajax it always fail. i dont understand why. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to create a proxy at your application which in turn will call the other domain and will return you the data:

```
function getLeague() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/crossdomainData',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Success');
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('Fail');
    }
    });
}
```

As you are using django, you can import this [**Django HTTP Proxy**](http://django-http-proxy.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installation.html).

> #### Introduction
>
> Django HTTP Proxy provides simple HTTP proxy functionality for the Django web development framework. ***It allows you make requests to an external server by requesting them from the main server running your Django application.*** In addition, it allows you to record the responses to those requests and play them back at any time.

---

Another option is here [taken from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12260186/1059101) answered by [@dvcrn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/728528/dvcrn).

```
import urllib2
    def crossdomainData(request):
        url = "http://otherdomain.ashx?username=xxx&password=xxx&sportsBook=xxx&sportsType=xxx&gameType=xxx"
        req = urllib2.Request(url)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        return HttpResponse(response.read(), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: Nice one. Doesn't this increase overhead on main server though?

Comment: @Wtower im sorry, i dont really understand about how server works. but, actually i didnt install django-http-proxy. i just follow the function Jai gave. and i works even without installing django-http-proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Some 500 errors happen earlier than the CORS middleware, so it has no chance to add CORS headers. If the response status code was 500, this might be the issue and CORS might be working fine.